# Clipping Library Difference issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, polygon, mesh, clipping

I started using Clipping Library from this site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/

I am working in Unity(C#).

Everything works great, unions, intersections, differences... yeah, difference, there is one case that the I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or the algorithm can not handle right.
[image]

I am trying to get the difference A-B and it should look like the one from Picture 2), unfortunately the output is mesh A and mesh B as in the picture 1).

What i do:

```
Clipper c = new Clipper();
c.AddPath(here goes the vertices of mesh A, polyType.Subject, true);
c.AddPath(here goes the vertices of mesh B, polyType.Clip, true);
c.Execute(ClipType.ctDIfference, a list of lists for my output,     PolyFillType.NonZero, PolyFillType.NonZero);
```

I've already tried to change PolyFillTypes but it changed nothing. And here I am, asking for your advices :)

EDIT: 
What I want to get(as in the picture "expected result") is the mesh with a hole.
What I actually get is 2-element List of Lists with exactly the same vertices I gave as an Input so when I create meshes from those vertices there is no one mesh with a hole, but one mesh overlaying another and Z-Fighting. There should be some function that I can create Mesh with a hole with but I can not manage to find it. As I saw in the GUIDEMO for C# version of this library it works, I saw the map (probably Australia) with cut hole in the middle of it.

Input: Vertices A(as a subject): (0,0), (0,10), (10,10), (10,0).
       Vertices B(as a clip): (2,8), (6,8), (6,2), (2,2).
Output is exactly the same: 
`List<List<IntPoint>>` that is 2-element and contains those two lists You can see above.

Comment: It would help if you showed the result **coordinates** you're getting from the clipping op, and then the coordinates that you were expecting.

Comment: I Edited my Post so you can see the point more clearly. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I have this identical problem (unity 3d c#), have you found a solution? Is clipperlib the right tool to achieve the "C" vertices?

Answer (score 1):

The clipping solution I get is:

```
(((10, 10),(0, 10),(0, 0),(10, 0)), ((2, 2),(2, 8),(6, 8),(6, 2)))
```

Note the different orientations of the 2 paths. This indicates that the inner path is a hole to the outer path (polygon) with either non-zero or even-odd filling rule.

Comment: That's correct, the question now is how to Get that hole? I am new to this library(maybe two hours of studying this) could you lead me to the solution that I am desperately looking for ?

Comment: Are u there? :) Really need this

Comment: Same problem here!
Have you found a solution? I'm stuck too at "how i GET the hole" part, i understand the solution gives back 2 sperate polygons one representing the outline and another the hole, can the library give back only one mesh with a hole?